# Wordpress and javascript .load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have problem to get .load() function working in Wordpress. Initially I was using 3.0.5 version of WP, wanted to get some content from external page (same domain), so I used this code

```
jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".someclass").load("http://www.mydomain.com #someid");
 });
```

...and it worked. However, after update of Wordpress to latest version (and installation of plugins /some use jquery or mootools/, this piece of code isnt pulling any content anymore. I tried to write different code for noConflict mode but also without success (but JS is working if I change line to some alert func). I also deactivated all plugins, removed other js (like for menu), but still no content was displayed. If I use same code in a separate file (in the same directory where WP theme is) - it works.

I would be thankful if someone have advice what to try next or where to look for potential problem. Or maybe to suggest some other approach how to get content from external page (and specific div). If I put that separate file into iframe and call it within sidebar, it's working but then there's a problem of iframe links opening within iframe box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which in lamens terms means you can't do ajax requests to different domains (even subdomains) as it is security risk, you browser simply won't let you do it. Specifically in your case you are attempting to load **www**.infostar.rs from inforstar.rs.

You will need to come up with another idea, personally I would just do it in PHP with:

```
 echo file_get_contents('http://domain.com');
```

Alternatively would could look into forcing non-www in htaccess.

Comment: Yes, I have <script>...As for errors, when I check with firebug it doesnt give any.

Comment: Hm, I feel that you're somewhere on the right track. I'm little bit confused since it was working before I updated WP. Not sure if there were any changes to .htaccess file. I notice now that if I have www. I get (in firebug console) GET (url) 200 ok (and than red circle with white cross). And if I remove www. message is GET (url) 301 Moved Permanently. But anyway thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @jan tot I'm pretty sure I'm right tbh. Forcing non-www is something you want to do for SEO anyway, otherwise google treats it as 2 different sites.

Comment: Yes. It's working now. Since on the main domain there's other platform (and I dont have access to it), and WP is within /blog, for now I changed it's url to use www. also, and now everything is ok.